# The evaluation of 'if' expressions

Tags: c++, if-statement, short-circuiting

Consider I have the following:

```
edge some_edge;
std::priority_queue<edge> my_queue;
```

Is it safe to write such an 'if' even if the queue might be empty?

```
if ((my_queue.size() > 0) && (my_queue.top().weight < some_edge.weight)) {
    do_something;
}
```

What about this one?

```
if ((my_queue.top().weight < some_edge.weight) && (my_queue.size() > 0)) {
    do_something;
}
```

Does evaluating an expression in which 'and' is the operator between the operands stop if the left operand evaluates false?

Comment: `if` is a statement in C++, not an expression. And yes, C++ is required to short-circuit evaluation (as long as no overloaded `operator&&` or `operator||` is involved).

Comment: But the things we're talking about evaluating in this context are expressions, @Ildjarn. The fact that they're inside "if" statements isn't actually relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `if` statement in C++ is left to right associative and the logical boolean operators `&&` and `||` are short circuiting, so yes, a statement like the following is safe because it is guaranteed that you check the size first (assuming no evil overloading of these operators):

```
if(myqueue.size() > 0 && myqueue.top().whatever) {
    // ...
}
```

The reverse is not true however because you check the return value of `size()` *after* popping the queue.

As an aside, `std::priority_queue` provides an `empty()` function that I/many would prefer over `size() > 0`, but that works too.

```
if(!myqueue.empty() && myqueue.top().whatever()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: IMO, it would be better *not* to mention associativity here -- order of evaluation is not determined by associativity, but by sequence points.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this behaviour is guaranteed per the C++ standard.

```
if (false && doSomething())
```

will never evaluate `doSomething()`.

However, if you overload `operator&&`, all expressions are evaluated so this behaviour could differ. This is why it's a bad idea to touch `operator&&`.

You should use `!empty()` instead of `size() > 0` though.

Answer (score 2):

This really isn't about `if` at all, it's about `&&`. The logical operator (both `&&` and `||`) evaluate their left operand first. Then if and only if the right operand could affect the logical result, they evaluate the right operand.

In the case of `&&`, if the left operand evaluates to `false`, the result will be `false` regardless of the right operand's value, so the right operand will not be evaluated.

In the case of `||`, if the left operand evaluates to `true`, the result will be `true` regardless of the right operand's value, so the right operand will not be evaluated.

This is true whether the `&&` is in the expression of an `if` statement or not. Some obfuscated code makes use of this by turning `if (x) y;` into `x && y`. Though not see as often, you *can* do the same with `||` as well.

Comment: Well, it *is* about the `if` statement in that it must guarantee left to right execution in order for this to work, but yeah, more to do with short circuiting.

Comment: @EdS.: The point is that the `if` just evaluates an expression. The expression itself enforces the left to right evaluation, regardless of whether it's in an `if` statement or not.

Answer (score 1):

This link explains how this is not true for all operators, even though it is true for &&. In particular, note the difference between left-to-right/right-to-left in the context of associativity versus order of evaluation. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Answer (score 0):

Boolean expressions are short-circuit evaluated, so if the first part fails, the second will not run. So the first example will not access nonexistant memory, but the second one will.